# load jQuery into a file via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an idea where I would like to load jQuery (via CDN) into a JavaScript file that when called on the page loads jQuery via the CDN and also loads the JavaScript file. so instead of doing:

```
<script>jquery</script>
<script>myscript></script>
```

I would just do:

```
<script>myscript</script>
```

and then jQuery would just load.... Because in the `myscript.js` I would be doing something like: *call jQuery via CDN .... do js code here that uses jQuery ...*

Comment: So where is the problem? Simple approach: Just insert `<script>` tag for jQuery.

Comment: @Sirko You can't do a `<script>` tag inside a .js file .... ??

Comment: @LogicLooking I can do something like `document.getElementById( 'target' ).innerHTML += '<script src="jquery.from.some.where"></script>';`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although we can hope for [a module solution in a near future](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3amodules), JavaScript currently doesn't allow for simple script dependency management.

You have a few solutions, the two main ones are :

- you write in your code a `script` element
- you use a library which manages dependencies like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)

If you want to use RequireJS, then you'd better read [the guide dedicated to importing jQuery](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html).

Today, with the current state of the import management in browsers, I would generally recommend to be less ambitious and to simply import with a classical `script` element. But RequireJS is interesting and you might find it useful when your application grows.

Comment: Damn I wanted to essentially write a library that sat on top of jquery to do some custom stuff but I didnt want people to have to go out and get jquery - I just wanted it all packaged as one

Comment: #1 sounds horrible; why would you suggest this?

Comment: @JanDvorak Well, it's common. Look at the other answer. I, at least, didn't give the code because I don't advocate using it (but it works).

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your script:

```
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/js/jquery-X.X.X.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
```

Comment: [Don’t docwrite scripts](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2012/04/10/dont-docwrite-scripts/)

Comment: this will cause the browser to become unresponsive until jQuery is loaded.

Comment: While I agree with the downside, to my mind this is the solution to the question. I would certainly advocate using the CDN as it was intended, or bundling the library with the site.

Comment: @chris you _can_ load asynchronously from a CDN.